# Не запускается активити из-за ошибки, которой раньше не было

Tags: java, android, activity

Не трогал код этого класса вообще, всегда он работал как надо и не выдавал ошибок. Этот класс мне нужен для запуска фоновой музыки. Как-то раз я заметил, что у меня эта музыка в папке assets находится и в raw.Подумал, что одна из них лишняя и надо удалить. Удалил сначала в raw, понял, что тупанул, т.к. ресурс от туда беру. Удалил в assets, почему-то перестала запускаться активити. Думаю, ладно, верну тогда всё как было, пусть и там, и там будет музыка. Вернул, но вышла ошибка в коде, которой никогда раньше не возникала. Я уже делал возврат к последнему рабочему коммиту, делал CleanProject, RebuildProject, ничего не помогает избавиться от неё.

Помогите у кого какие идеи на этот счёт? Код я вообще не трогал, только вот музыку удалял и то уже всё на свои места вернул.

Ошибка:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{dc.galos/dc.galos.View.Authorization}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(int)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2650)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2720)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1567)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5917)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(int)' on a null object reference
    at dc.galos.Controller.Sound.initialization(Sound.java:15)
    at dc.galos.View.Authorization.onCreate(Authorization.java:38)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6286)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2603)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2720) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1567) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5917) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
```

Сказано, что активити пытается вызвать метод, который ссылается на нулевой объект (хотя раньше прекрасно вызывался).

Сам код, в котором этот метод на нулевой объект ссылается:

```
public class Sound {

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    private static boolean volume = true;

    public void initialization(Context context, int res_id) {
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, res_id);
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
    }

    public void mediaStart() {
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    public void mediaStop() {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
    }

    public static boolean isVolume() {
        return volume;
    }

    public static void setVolume(boolean volume) {
        Sound.volume = volume;
    }
}
```

Здесь проблема в строке `mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);` судя по ошибке. `AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC` видимо является `null`, хотя повторюсь, раньше оно таковым не являлось. Как можно это исправить?

Вызываю метод в другой активити, которая как раз и не запускается таким образом:

```
sound.initialization(this, R.raw.background_music);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй переписать несколько строк, связанные с этим вызовом, так как у меня также часто бывает, что при откате некоторые объекты ругаются мол так нельзя, откуда ты это взял, и пока вручную снова не забьешь не компилится, также советую проследить путь где он теряет файл, а может он вообще в папку не заходит и тогда понятно почему null

Comment: Спасибо большое. Я код переписывал, благодаря вам задумался действительно перезалить файл с музыкой. Удалил её из assets (она там ни к чему все равно), удалил из raw и перезалил туда. Запустил и всё заработало :)

Answer (score 1):

Ваша ошибка:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.**`setAudioStreamType`**(int)' **on a null object reference**

По-русски:

> Метод **`setAudioStreamType`** не может быть вызван на **`несуществующем объекте`**.

В вашей строке кода `mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)` этот метод вы вызываете у вашего `mediaPlayer`, и `null` именно он, а не `AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC`.

А значит `null` у вас возвращает `MediaPlayer.create(context, res_id)`. Проверьте, почему так выходит.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Видимо проблемы с ресурсом были, я его перезалил и ошибки больше нет.